# Total days between 2 dates C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve a problem that asks me to give the total days between two dates.

I have to take care of some issues between those two dates, such as leap years and the way of inputting the years by the users. (For example, if you input 1 and 17, the code will still give you the difference is 16 years (2017 - 2001 = 16). I am not supposed to change ANYTHING inside the `main()` function.

Here is my code.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>

 using namespace std;

 class date
 {
    private:
    int m;
    int d;
    int y;

    public:
    date(int, int, int);
    int countLeapYears(date&);
    int getDifference(date&);
    int operator-(date&);    
  };

   int main()
   {
    int day, month, year;
    char c;

    cout << "Enter a start date: " << endl;
    cin >> month >> c >> day >> c >> year;

    date start = date(month, day, year);

    cout << "Enter an end date: " << endl;
    cin >> month >> c >> day >> c >> year;

    date end = date(month, day, year);
    int duration = end-start;

     cout << "The number of days between those two dates are: " <<    
     duration << endl;

     return 0;
   }


    date::date(int a, int b, int c)
    {
    m = a;
    d = b;
    y = c;
    }

    const int monthDays[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31,   
    30, 31};

   int date::countLeapYears(date& d)
   {
      int years = d.y;
      if (d.m <= 2)
      years--;
      return years / 4 - years / 100 + years / 400;
    }

   int date::getDifference(date& other)
   {

      int n1 = other.y*365 + other.d;

      for (int i=0; i<other.m - 1; i++)
     {
       n1 += monthDays[i];
       n1 += countLeapYears(other);
      }

      return n1;
      }

   int date::operator-(date& d) {
      int difference = getDifference(d);
      return difference;
    }
```

When I ran this code, it said `invalid binary operation between "date" and "date"`.

Now, I assume that when I initialized `int duration = end - start`, I should have gotten a number. I guess what I am doing wrong here is I failed to convert the (end - start) date type into an integer. I thought my function getDifference already took care of that issue, but apparently it did not.

Comment: `2007 - 2001` is the same thing as `7 - 1`, I don't really see what's dicey about that.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Do you mean that you should accept input `7` as if the user entered `2007`? If so, just check if the entered year is less than `2000` and add `2000` in that case.

Comment: @DUman Thanks! My brain is not working today. After that, in the main() function, when I compile, it says int duration = end - start is not valid because I got from class date to an int type. Any tip to solve this?

Comment: `-`, the subtraction operator, is not defined for your class. Your compiler doesn't know how to subtract your `date` objects, they're not numbers. C++ lets you define operators such as `+` or `-` for your classes. The term to search for is "operator overloading".

Comment: Or you just don't use the `-` syntax and use a differently-named function such as your `getDifference`.

Comment: @DUman I created a new overloading operator -. But when I return, I still get a date right? Should I create another function that take the argument from this operator- and convert it into integer of days somehow? I tried getDifference but when I cout << getDifference (start, end), it won't compile. It said undeclared getDifference.

Comment: Yes, `operator-` would return a date. If you want an integer, you need another function. Also look up "function prototypes". Your `getDifference` is undeclared at the time when you use it, so the compiler cannot find it. You need a prototype or just to move the function to before you first use it.

Comment: @DUman it is so hard to pick up C++ by myself haha

Comment: @DUman I updated my code above. I still have an issue. Do you know why? When I ran it, it said invalid binary operation between "date" and "date". Now, I assume that when I initialized int duration = end - start, I should have got a number. I guess what I am doing wrong here is I failed to convert the (end - start) date type into integer. I thought my function getDifference already took care of that issue. Somehow, it appeared that I did not take care of that issue.

Comment: @Hugh It will not convert if you use `-`, you need to call your `getDifference` function. It doesn't know what you mean by `-`. And you should probably change your function to take two `date`s as arguments and count the difference between them. Instead of having two functions.

Comment: @DUman Now i have an overloading Operator. Yay! but I got the wrong result. The difference between 1/1/1992 and 1/1/2016, as the code gave me, was 727084. I have no clue.

Comment: @DUman I got it now. Thanks Gosh. Thanks Duman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Challenge accepted.

Using this [free, open-source, header-only date library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html):

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace me
{

class date
{
    ::date::sys_days tp_;
public:
    date(int month, int day, int year)
        : tp_{::date::year(year)/month/day}
        {}

    friend
    int
    operator-(const date& x, const date& y)
    {
        return (x.tp_ - y.tp_).count();
    }
};

}  // namespace me

using namespace std;
#define date me::date

int main()...
```

Comment: That looks amazing, but I am not supposed to use date.h to solve this puzzle. My friend gave me hint by using operator overloading, and I am not supposed to change the main() function. I am still working on it.

Comment: @Hugh: Actually most really solid date algorithms are more advanced than homework-level coding.  For people who want to write their own date code I over these public domain algorithms: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html

Comment: Hello Mr Howard, I have an issue with my code above, and I need your help please. When I ran it, it said invalid binary operation between "date" and "date". Now, I assume that when I initialized int duration = end - start, I should have got a number. I guess what I am doing wrong here is I failed to convert the (end - start) date type into integer. I thought my function getDifference already took care of that issue. Somehow, it appeared that I did not take care of that issue.

Comment: @Hugh:  Search your book, or whatever class materials you have for the subject: "overloading operators".